# create-react-app 原因不明のエラー ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, windows-10, reactjs, npm

**前提・実現したいこと**

create-react-app の実行時にエラーが発生しており、解決できません...
8時間ほどかけて試行錯誤しましたが、挫折してしまいました...
ご教授願います。。。

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

```
node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-04T15_56_34_118Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts@0.9.x has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
```

**試したこと**

https://qiita.com/k-murayama/items/014e3745290208b92af1 
こちらのページの通り、

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app react-sample
```

と
作業を進めていると、create-react-appで上記のようなエラーが出ました。

Nodeのバージョンアップ,create-react-appの再インストールを行いましたが、同様の結果になりました。

インターネット検索したところ、同じ症状の解決策に
`\Users\username` 内にある`.npmrc`の削除、
windows defender のリアルタイムスキャンの無効
`npm cache clean --force`の施行

などが記載されていましたが、どれを試してもうまくいきませんでした。

**補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）**

- node -v: v12.16.3
- npm  -v: 6.9.0
- windows10

ログの内容

```
24822 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\6.9.0\lib\install\deps.js:448:9)
24822 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\6.9.0\lib\install\deps.js:448:9)
24822 verbose stack     at failedDependency (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\6.9.0\lib\install\deps.js:448:9)
24823 verbose cwd C:\Users\siawase88946\sample
24824 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
24825 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\v-x64\\12.16.3\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\npmv\\6.9.0\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts@0.9.x"
24826 verbose node v12.16.3
24827 verbose npm  v6.9.0
24828 error Maximum call stack size exceeded
24829 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: `.npmrc`を消しても駄目だったけど `_auth` 項目をコメントアウトしたり空文字にしたりするとうまくいったみたいなことも書かれたりしていましたが([1](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8795#issuecomment-467790060), [2](https://npm.community/t/always-reproducible-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-npm-install-error/1645/13))、この対応では上手く行くでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。初歩的な質問で申し訳ないのですが、`.npmrc`内の`_auth`項目をコメントアウトとは、どのように行えばよいのでしょうか？`.npmrc`の中身`npm config edit`でのぞいてみたのですが、`_auth`項目はありませんでした...

Comment: 自分もさほど詳しい訳では無いのでリンク先を読んだ上での推測になりますが…/[`.npmrc`ファイル](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/npmrc.html)はプロジェクトごと設定、ユーザごと設定、...というようにいくつかの読み込むファイルと、それらが有効化される優先順位が決まっています。`_auth`はプライベートレジストリのクレデンシャル設定のようですが、有効化されているクレデンシャル設定がおかしいと今回のエラーになるので、プロジェクトごと設定の `~/.npmrc` に `_auth=""` を書くことでそのおかしい設定を上書きしてしまって解消した、というのが[この方](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8795#issuecomment-467790060)が言わんとしていることかな、と。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。`C:/Users/Username/.npmrc`に`_auth=""`を`npm config set _auth=""` を用いて記述しましたが、同様のエラーが出てしまいました...

Comment: 以下のファイルの内容を、転記すると、詳しい人にはわかるかもしれません。
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-04T15_56_34_118Z-debug.log

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。追記いたしました。

Comment: エラーメッセージの`node -e ...`の上の行も追記お願いできますか？おそらく、`core-js@2.6.11 postinstall`というようなログが出ているはずです。また使用中のPCのメモリー容量はいくつでしょうか？

Comment: windows defenderが邪魔している可能性も高いです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230006/create-react-app-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceededat-object-mkdirsync
 を参考にしてみてください。

Comment: himenon様 `core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\username\ins\node_modules\core-js` となっております.メモリ容量は8GBです。

Comment: windows defenderの無効化も試しましたが、解決しませんでした...

Comment: ログにある、”verbose stack     at failedDependency ”は、「リクエストに失敗した、その原因はそれ以前のリクエスト依存していたのに、依存していたリクエストが失敗したから」というような意味だと思います
 Aさんに頼んでた仕事の結果を見て、自分の仕事を進めるつもりだったのに、Aさんがしくじったから、自分の仕事もダメになった、みたいな失敗の連鎖が起きた。しくじった仕事の書類が机に積まれた。その繰り返しで机に書類を積みきれなくなって、どうしようもなくなった(Stack Overflow)
 どのようなリクエストが行われたのかを探って、失敗の連鎖を止める方法（例えば、例外が起きたら、そこで実行中止する）を考えてみては如何でしょう？